# Help with deploying asp.net web app to an existing website

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, deployment, publish

I've built a asp.net web app, and i'm ready to publish it to the intranet to further test it.  I already have a server running IIS 6.

The site is currently setup as the Default Web Site.  I want to install this new web app in a subdirectory, so that it doesn't impact on my main site  http://MyCurrentSite at all..   How do I do this?

I'm new to IIS, so I really don't want to screw things up :-)

Cheers for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very simple operation.  Just create a "virtual directory" in your "Default Web Site" and map the virtual directory to the directory with the files for your new web site.

Comment: Ah ok.. I saw virtual directories, but was reluctant to push buttons without knowing which ones to push (there are so many)
Thanks

Comment: Don't forget to select this as the accepted answer once you get it to work.